# How can I calculate $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right) \left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right) f(w; \mu, \sigma²)\,\mathrm dw$

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution

Suppose $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution and $f(\cdot; \mu, \sigma²)$ is the density of the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.

Is it possible to give a closed form solution for the integral:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right) \left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right) f(w; \mu, \sigma²)\,\mathrm dw?$$

I realized that this is related to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw). I tried using integration by substitution and by parts but didn't get to a solution. Is there a closed form expression for this integral?

Comment: The result you reference makes it easily possible (via linear substitutions and completing the square) to compute the integral of $\Phi((w-a)/b)f(w;\mu,\sigma^2) \exp(\lambda (w-a)/b)dw$. The MacLaurin series of that function of $\lambda$ will yield integrals proportional to $\Phi((w-a)/b)((w-a)/b)^k f(w;\mu,\sigma^2)dw$ for $k=0, 1, 2, \ldots$; you want the case $k=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I solved $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right) \exp\left(\frac{\lambda(w-a)}{b}\right) f(w; \mu, \sigma²)\,\mathrm dw$ as you proposed. However, I don't get how I can now use the MacLaurin series to get back to original problem. What is unclear to me: (1) what would I do with the terms of the series for $k\geq 2$? (2) The series would be a function of some $x$, which doesn't occur in the original problem. How could that be adressed?

Comment: You ignore all terms except for the $k=1$ coefficient, which (upon multiplication by $1!=1$) yields the result you are looking for.